# Liquibase not able to connect to RDS via DNS name in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, devops

I'm facing a issue on jenkins. I'm trying to connect Liquibase to my RDS (Aurora Mysql) in Jenkins through DNS name and getting the below error:

> Unexpected error running Liquibase: Connection could not be created to
> jdbc:mariadb://{mydnsname}:3306/mydb?createdatabaseIfNotExist=true
> with driver org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver. Could not connect to
> address=(host=mydnsanme)(port=3306)(type=master) : (conn=1542578)
> could not load system variables

Now, the same thing works if just directly provide the RDS endpoint instead of DNS name. Also, I'm able to access my RDS database everywhere using the DNS name even inside the Jenkins server.
Can anyone please provide any insights on this issue?